# how to use correctly expressions in choice in mule esb

Tags: java, xml, mule, esb

I've two kind of a variables in payload. I would like to use simple choice. If one of this is null then choose other, for instance:

```
<choice>
  <when expression="#[groovy:airportRequest.getCountryCode() != (null || '')]">

  </when>
  <otherwise>

  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

I dunno why first condition is always true. Even though in `CountryCode` is null or empty space.

Comment: Mention your config file in the post. That wold help in giving a good solution.

Comment: What Mule version do you use?

Comment: The != (null || '') construction looks a little unusual to me. Could it be evaluating the (null || '') first (and producing an intermediate result of, say, 0) and then you're checking your country code against 0? The way to test out my thinking would be to have it != '' and then feed it an empty country code. I'm sure Mule wouldn't mind having two expressions here.

Comment: Did you try breaking this conditional statement into two seperate conditions using or '||' operator.

Comment: it was wrong syntax for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working:

```
<when expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(airportRequest.getCountryCode())]">
```

and also:

```
<when expression="airportRequest.getCountryCode() != empty">
```

As documentation says:

> In MEL, the keyword empty tests the emptiness of a value, and returns
>   boolean true for any of the following:
>
> null boolean false empty strings or strings with only white space 0
>   value numeric values empty collections
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Examples

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about: `<when expression="airportRequest.countryCode != empty">` ?